# Troubleshooting pyarrow reading Parquet file (row count correct, but table contains no rows)

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I'm working in a JupyterLab notebook using Python 3 with `pandas` and `pyarrow`. I have some AWS cost data stored in Parquet format (file is stored locally). I'm trying to read this data into a Pandas DataFrame with `read_parquet`:

```py
df = pd.read_parquet(datafile)
len(df.index)
```

This is returning `0`, and `display(df)` confirms that there are no rows in the DataFrame:

```
identity_line_item_id   identity_time_interval  bill_invoice_id     ... [156 columns]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 rows × 156 columns
```

However, if I try examining the file with `pyarrow`:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

pqfile = pq.ParquetFile(datafile)
table = pq.read_table(datafile)

pqfile.metadata
```

Notebook shows:

```
<pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at 0x119641188>
  created_by: parquet-mr version 1.8.2-SNAPSHOT (build 65c96b16c98f9d933b98681d5f2f9e2410abe85c)
  num_columns: 156
  num_rows: 999841
  num_row_groups: 1
  format_version: 1.0
  serialized_size: 18171
```

So the number of rows in the file is close to 1M. However if I then try to read the rows:

```
rg = pqfile.read_row_group(0)
rg.num_rows
```

Last line returns "0" again. Which is the same result I get if I just call `pq.read_table` or `pq.read_table(...).to_pandas()` ([per example in the Arrow docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html)).

I've installed parquet-tools and can read the schema and meta-data and get the same row count. But I don't get any rows read into either a Pandas DataFrame or a Pyarrow Table.

First time working with this data so looking for things to try in order to troubleshoot the problem. Any ideas?

UPDATE 1: Noticed that in the schema report from `parquet-tools` every field is REQUIRED, but when I use the cat sub-command many fields do not have an apparent value. Would that cause the rows to not be loaded?

UPDATE 2: A colleague has successfully read the file in their own Python + pyarrow environment, but seems to have different packages and package versions. Trying to reproduce his environment now.

UPDATE 3: The Parquet file is generated and stored in S3 by AWS. It's part of their "AWS Cost & Usage Reports" available in their Billing Management. The file is generated to be loaded later into Athena although I'm not using it that way.

UPDATE 4: My code works now if I use Jupyter Notebook (6.0.1). Does not work in JupyerLab (1.1.3). Trying to work out what the difference is...

Comment: Can you share an example code on how this file was generated?

Comment: The Parquet file is generated and stored in S3 by AWS as an "AWS Cost & Usage Report." The settings are to generate it "for Athena" and compression method set to "Parquet"